# What does "slept with a hanger in your mouth" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the pilot episode of *Friends* Monica meets this handsome guy and they have sex in her flat. Next day in the morning, she kisses him off and then she has this conversation with Rachel:

> Monica: So how're you doing today?
>   You-you sleep ok? You talked to Barry? I can't stop smiling.
>
> Rachel: I can see that. You look like
>   you slept with a hanger in your
>   mouth.
>
> Monica: I know, he, he's just so... You
>   remember you and Tony DeMarco?
>
> Rachel Oh, yeah.
>
> Monica: Well, it's like that. With feelings
>
> Rachel: Oh wow. Are you in trouble.
>
> Monica: Big time!

I have no idea what hanger means here and how it is related to her smiling.

Answer (score 6):

She means that Monica's smile was so wide, and given the fact that she couldn't control smiling, was metaphorically compared to having a hanger inside her mouth, overnight, which would force her jaw open, to make it look like she was smiling, as shown below.

[image]

Since she couldn't stop smiling due to her night with that guy, which obviously is the reason for her super-wide smile, Rachael used the phrase '*you slept with a hanger in your mouth*' to try and relate to why she couldn't stop smiling, to having Monica's jaw forced to take the shape of a smile by retaining a hanger in her mouth all night.

Comment: To make it more clear, a hanger is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clothes_hanger).

Comment: I guess it means smiling with a wide mouth. This kind of slang exists in Persian too.

Answer (score 0):

A hanger (used for hanging clothes on) in your mouth make your mouth wide open, not vertically but horizontally.